# Setting DarkTheme has no effect Braintree iOS v4 SDK

Tags: swift, braintree

The documentation clearly says it can be done, easy breezy:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/ios/v4#themes

I can indeed customize the primaryTextColor to red.

Here is a screenshot, that demonstrates that red works but not darkTheme:
[image]

And is here is my code in my UIViewController:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: clientToken)
    }

    func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
        BTUIKAppearance.darkTheme()
        BTUIKAppearance.sharedInstance().primaryTextColor = UIColor.red

        let request =  BTDropInRequest()
        request.vaultManager = true

        let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
        { (controller, result, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("ERROR")
            } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
                print("CANCELLED")
            } else if let result = result {
                // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
                // result.paymentOptionType
                // result.paymentMethod
                // result.paymentIcon
                // result.paymentDescription
            }
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So Braintree's [documentation on Theme's](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/ios/v4#themes) is a bit poorly choose wording IMO.

The instruction is what is misleading to me: "To use the Dark theme instead, call this method before initializing Drop-in". Yet you have to initialize or instantiate the drop-in before setting darkTheme.

The instruction might better read: "To use the Dark theme instead, call this method before presenting the Drop-in"

Here is my working code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: clientToken)
}

func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
    let request =  BTDropInRequest()
    request.vaultManager = true

    dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
    { (controller, result, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR")
        } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
            print("CANCELLED")
        } else if let result = result {
            // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
            // result.paymentOptionType
            // result.paymentMethod
            // result.paymentIcon
            // result.paymentDescription
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    BTUIKAppearance.darkTheme()
    BTUIKAppearance.sharedInstance()?.primaryTextColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```